# Use independent MySQL installation with PHP that came with XAMPP 1.6.2

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, lampp, mysql.sock

I have installed XAMPP 1.6.2 (need this use this specific version) at /opt/lampp in Ubuntu 16.0.4.
I have installed Mysql 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 using apt-get. 
I need to use the installed version of MySQL with PHP that came with XAMPP.

When I try to connect PHP with MySQL (independent installation), I get this error:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'

I am still getting this error after trying the following things:

1. Replaced all occurrences of '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' with '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' in /opt/lampp directory.
2. Restarted Apache, MySQL.
3. Rebooted system.
4. Searched on Stackoverflow, and tried existing solutions (eg. edit my.cnf)

Please help me out;
Thanks.

Comment: is the mysql service running?

Comment: yes, 
i have tried to restart it as well.
It didn't help

Comment: Are you sure it's the right MySQL service? (as in, the 5.7 version)

Comment: yes.
But the MySQL that came with XAMPP has lower version (5.0.41).

Comment: are you able to connect using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` for your connection?

Comment: wow, I got connected.
Thanks FMashiro :)

Could you please explain why this works ?

Comment: when connecting to localhost, the socket connector is used, but when connecting to the IP address the  TCP/IP connector is used. This could mean that the path to the socket is incorrect or that the socket is corrupted (the first case being more likely), try going to that path and seeing if it actually exists.

Comment: I checked that path, it does exist. Issue might have occurred due to incompatibility.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue simply by replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 in my.cnf file.
As [Fmashiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4461980/fmashiro) pointed out, this could have happened due to missing / corrupted socket file.